How is $L = \bigcup_{\alpha\in\text{Ord}}L_\alpha$ defined in ZFC?
The following is from Jech's Set Theory:

Is $L$ actually defined in ZFC? If so, how is the union over all ordinals taken?

Please don't use images for mathematical texts.

Four questions in a few minutes about stuff in a textbook, maybe that's not the right textbook for you.

@GerryMyerson I go through sections of the textbook writing aside the doubts. After that, I try to answer the doubts I have. The remaining doubts I ask here. Hence why they were all asked in a short span of time.

Unbounded unions aren't a problem unless you're trying to argue that the thing you get at the end is a set; e.g. if $\varphi(x,y)$ is any formula, then we can define $$\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathsf{Ord}}\{x:\varphi(x,\alpha)\}$$ as $$\{x: \exists\alpha\in\mathsf{Ord}\varphi(x,\alpha)\}.$$ So long as you have the relevant formula $\varphi$ to work with, this is perfectly nice. (Of course there's no reason to expect the end result to be a set, but sethood is different from definability.)

So how do we get the relevant $\varphi$ in this case? Well, we're using a really handy "sequence-coding" trick: our $\varphi(x,y)$ will be the formula stating that

$y$ is an ordinal, and

there is some function $f$ with domain $y$ such that

$\exists z\in y(x\in f(z))$,

$f(0)=\emptyset$,

$f(\lambda)=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}f(\beta)$ for $\lambda<y$ limit, and

$f(\beta+1)=\mathcal{P}_{def}(f(\beta))$ for $\beta+1<y$ (where $\mathcal{P}_{def}$ is the definable powerset operation; alternatively, take the closure under the Godel operations).




Intuitively, $\varphi(x,y)$ says "$y$ is an ordinal and $x\in L_y$."
It's also worth noting that essentially the same sequence-coding trick gets used in theories of arithmetic too (e.g. when showing that every computable function is representable in Peano arithmetic).
